Is there a way to access a mailbox with the DirectorySearcher and filtering it to each user's inbox?
I have admin rights to AD for our exchange server. I was asked to report any email address, not in the contacts, that a user has communicated with more than 5 times. I was thinking I would look through the emails sent to a person more than once outside of their contacts. I have this below, but with this can I access messages in an inbox from the user object?
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";

foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in dSearch.FindAll())
{
    //sResultSet.Properties find a property to access inbox messages
}

I could be approaching this the wrong way, if anyone has a better library to use to approach this would be great.

Mailbox contents are stored on mailbox database servers, not in the directory

Depending on the nature of the report/question, you'll probably want to use Exchange's eDiscovery tooling, or for short time windows, its message transport audit facility

@MathiasR.Jessen I understand it's not in the directory but I was wondering if the user object would drill down to the users inbox. Thanks for clarifying

Objects in AD are just that - objects - collections of data. They don't "do" anything or "drill down" into anything - they just exist :)

I think the safest approach would be:
The script should use get-messagetrackinglog cmdlet to look for messages sent from your organization to outside (if I did not understand incorrectly) and there are at least five messages with the same Sent-To email address. It would be wise to output from and to addresses to a table (format-table), then optimize and search for the required messages.
If the contact folder location is their local disk (pst), this would be difficult or even impossible (for ex. password protected pst files can not be decrypted) to investigate whether destination address is a person out of their contacts. For this to work you should block pst usage for users and move all common contacts to Exchange Server creating the mail contacts in GAL (Global Address List). Then you can look for whether the repeated messaging occurs with a non-contact email address. For the personal contacts still in the mail folders of a mailbox a periodic scan with search-mailbox command should be done if required.
Message Tracking Logs should be kept for the number of days you will search backwards.
